# Video Card doesn't work without PS/2 Keyboard plugged into PS/2 Mouse port

Tags: graphics-card, windows-vista, nvidia-graphics-card, ps2

To make a very long story short, we had a computer in with an odd problem:  While the computer otherwise booted fine (Windows start-up sound played), The PCIe-16 video card would not display an image without a PS/2 keyboard plugged into the PS/2 port designated for the mouse.  I'm wondering why this happens.

It was kind of a happy accident that I discovered this at all, but ultimately it came down to pulling everything off the main board except a stick of RAM, the CPU, and the Power Supply.  The monitor was plugged into the on-board graphics, which I assume the BIOS defaulted to when it didn't find the video card.  I assume this because it worked fine.  Aside from not finding a bootable device (because none were plugged in), the display always came up

The moment I plugged a video card in, the display stopped coming up whether the monitor was plugged into the video card or the on-board graphics.  The only way to get the display to work (on the video card, since the on-board graphics wouldn't work while it was plugged in) was to plug a PS/2 keyboard into the PS/2 port designated for the mouse while the computer was powering up.  Once it was powered up, everything was fine.  The keyboard could be removed, or the computer could be restarted (as long as it wasn't powered down) with no problems.

Things I tried that didn't work:

- Disabling the PS/2 Mouse Detection in the BIOS.  This prevented me from getting any display at all until I pulled the CMOS.
- Switching which port the BIOS should search for the Video Card in.  Only valid options were On-Board (which ignored the video card), PCI, or PCIe-16.
- Swapping out the power supply and RAM.  No change in symptoms.
- Putting the PS/2 keyboard in the port designated for the keyboard, or a PS/2 mouse in the port designated for the mouse, or both.  Only the combination of the keyboard in mouse port worked, though I didn't have an extra PS/2 mouse or keyboard to try.
- Trying a different video card.  No change in symptoms.

I apologize for not having hardware specifics on hand.  I tried posting this while I was at the shop, and couldn't for some reason.  The computer was an HP with Windows Vista, and a Coworker recalls the motherboard being ASUS.  One of the video cards we tried in it (but not the one that came with it) was an NVidia GeForce 210.  Windows claimed the old card was an NVidia of some kind.

If anyone has come across this kind of thing before (even if you never figured out the cause), I'd appreciate your insight.

Comment: almost certainly a motherboard issue, maybe a short somewhere.

Comment: Can you see which IRQs are assigned with the PS/2 mouse plugged in and without it. (For without, remote desktop in).

Comment: Unfortunately, not at the moment.  We're hoping the customer will decide to give us the computer for recycling when they buy their new one, because this has become a bit of an office mystery, and we want another stab at it.